# image from xcassets iOS11

Tags: swift, uiimage, ios11, xcode9, xcasset

I have a set of images inside an .xcassets folder. 
Using iOS 11 and Xcode 9 I access them with

```
    func searchCodes() -> NSArray {

    let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PickerStations", withExtension: "plist")
                return NSArray(contentsOf: file!)!
    }

    lineCode = searchCodes().object(at: 1) as? NSDictionary

    //lineFirstInitial is either C,H,J,N,P,D,M,V,B or W
    let lineNameFromInitial = lineCode?.allKeys(for: lineFirstInitial).first as! String

    //lineNameFromInitial is 100% correct value and loaded from an array of Strings. 
//Looped through and each value added to the code below. 
                if let lineLabelImage = UIImage(named: lineNameFromInitial) {
                   lineLabelImageView.image = lineLabelImage
    }
```

Some Images enter the block and yet others do not as they return nil. However the images are 100% in the .xcassets and the file name is 100% correct. I have tried hardcoding the images name instead of passing the variable `lineNameFromInitial` but the images are still nil for some despite actually existing.

[image: xcassets]

The images are found using the keys in a plist
[image: plist]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your xcAssets and your string array?

Comment: Yes i have just updated with images

Comment: Which keys return nil?

Comment: That's the thing its seemingly random.

Comment: That's weird. Can you post the code that initializes `lineNameFromInitial`? By the way: unwrapping of the `UIImage` is not needed in your case because `lineLabelImageView.image` can handle `nil`

Comment: Ill add to question. As I mentioned thought that even if I hard code by typing "District" it still returns nil

Comment: I ran your code on my machine, but I could not reproduce the issue. The images are loading everytime.

Comment: I think i may need me to start a new project and migrate the files over as Xcode clearly has an issue with the files in the current project

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons that might be the reason for the images being nil:

**1. The images have not been added to your app's target.**

[image]

**2. The images have a name with special characters:**

Xcode does not like assets that have special characters like ÄÖÜ etc. in their name. Have a look at the problematic images' names and change those characters to plain old english characters.

Comment: They are added to app target. Will update original post to reflect. TY

Comment: Thanks for the note about special chars!